# In the HashiCorp Vault docs, "Lease IDs" are mentioned several times. How do I find one?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

In the Vault Web UI, under "Access", it shows the ability to look up leases by "Lease ID": `If you know the id of a lease, enter it above to lookup details of the lease.`

How do I get "the id of a lease" in the first place?

In the Vault CLI, it looks like my only options for leases are `renew` and `revoke`:

```
~ |   vault lease lookup
Usage: vault lease <subcommand> [options] [args]

  This command groups subcommands for interacting with leases. Users can revoke
  or renew leases.

  Renew a lease:

      $ vault lease renew database/creds/readonly/2f6a614c...

  Revoke a lease:

      $ vault lease revoke database/creds/readonly/2f6a614c...

Subcommands:
    renew     Renews the lease of a secret
    revoke    Revokes leases and secrets
```

If I just need to get a lease id, how would I do that from the CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, like many "missing commands" in the CLI, a little reading of the API docs resolved the issue.

No, there are no `vault lease lookup` or `vault lease list` commands.

But it turns out that the well-documented `LIST` HTTP request to `sys/leases/lookup` sort of corresponds to `vault list` on that same `sys/leases/lookup` path:

```
~ |   vault list sys/leases
No value found at sys/leases/
~ |   vault list sys/leases/lookup
Keys
----
auth/
~ |   vault list sys/leases/lookup/auth
Keys
----
approle/
token/
userpass/
~ |
```

Have fun exploring your leases today, by reviewing the following documentation:

What is a lease?
https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/identity/lease
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/lease.html

Vault API for Lease stuff: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/leases.html
Vault CLI for Lease stuff: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/lease/index.html

Comment: Hi, So if we want a secret to be alive for X time then which parameter we need to set? i see LeaseDuration & MaxLeaseTTL.

Comment: // , If you don't know which one, set MaxLeaseTTL.

Comment: // , Better yet, ask a question! Getting relevant technical content in Q&A format what this forum's all about, supposedly.